# mask function doesn't get rid of unwanted data

Tags: python, pandas, iot

I'm working on a data frame taken from Adafruit IO and sadly some of my data is from a time when my project malfunctioned so some of the values are just equal NaN.

I tried to remove it by typing this code lines:

```
    onlyValidData=temp_data.mask(temp_data['value'] =='NaN')
    onlyValidData
```

This is data retreived from Adafruit IO Feed, getting analyzed by pandas, I tried using 'where' function too but it didn't work

my entire code is

```
import pandas as pd

temp_data = pd.read_json('https://io.adafruit.com/api/(...)')
light_data = pd.read_json('https://io.adafruit.com/api/(...)')
temp_data['created_at'] =  pd.to_datetime(temp_data['created_at'], infer_datetime_format=True)

temp_data = temp_data.set_index('created_at')

light_data['created_at'] =  pd.to_datetime(light_data['created_at'], infer_datetime_format=True)
light_data = light_data.set_index('created_at')

tempVals = pd.Series(temp_data['value'])
lightVals = pd.Series(light_data['value'])

onlyValidData=temp_data.mask(temp_data['value'] =='NaN')
onlyValidData
```

The output is all of my data for some reason, but it should be only the valid values.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I think the issue here that you're looking for values equal to the string 'NaN', while actual NaN values aren't a string, or more specifically aren't anything.

Try using:

```
onlyValidData = temp_data.mask(temp_data['value'].isnull())
```

Edit: to remove rows rather than marking all values in that row as NaN:

```
onlyValidData = temp_data.dropna()
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, but for some reason - it does not do anything. no row at all was filtered.

Comment: Ah I see, you want the rows completely removed:

try:

    onlyValidData = temp_data.dropna()